# How to run single instance of calculator (calc.exe) in Windows

Tags: windows

In Windows 7, every time I start Calculator (calc.exe) (either using dedicated keyboard key or by typing "calc" in "Run" dialog box) a new instance of Calculator application is launched. I am looking for a way to activate existing instance (if present) of Calculator - bringing it in focus

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do that via programming? If so, what programming environment do you use? Or do you want to change the behaviour of Calc itself? The second variant would be off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/316541/force-an-application-to-be-single-instance

Comment: Thanks @NineBerry - I was looking for either windows native batch file or scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for the link @CodeCaster - I looked for simpler method to achieve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I created the following script:

```html
<package>
  <job id="js">
    <script languange="JScript">
      var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
      var ret = WshShell.AppActivate("Calculator");
      if (ret==false)
        WshShell.Run("calc");
    </script>
  </job>
</package>
```

and saved it to file named scalc.wsf, preferably this file should be save in directory present in %PATH%.
Now, if I type scalc.wsf - a script is called and single instance of Calculator is launched.
I also set the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AppKey\18\ShellExecute
to value "scalc.wsf". With this - every time I press the dedicated key - a script is launched and single instance of Calculator app is running